# Create Folder inside Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

i developing a new theme for my website and i want to add 2 languages inside it. but every language have it's own folder inside theme.

so i created two Folders (en) and (ar) inside my wordpress theme which everyone include php files but when the website loaded i can't access them and got a white page without any code inside it.

example:

1. www.website.com/en/index.php
2. www.website.com/ar/index.php

how i can create them and access them like normal html pages?

please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: You either need to use some language selection plugin or create a multi-site network, see [Multilingual wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The index.php for your homepage isn't in your Theme folder: it's in the top directory of the WordPress install.
For me (on Apache) the index.php you are talking about is at:

```
/public_html/index.php
```

You're modifying the index.php that (for me) is found at:

```
/public_html/wp-content/themes/mythemename/index.php
```

I'm pretty sure what you're wanting to do would look like this:

```
/public_html/en/index.php
```

Let me know if that works!